# java: FTP in multi threaded, multi user web application

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, static, ftp

I'm developing an application using Spring MVC. In a business process, an image file is generated which needs to retrieved to web server from the application server. I'm using the commons-net api to do it the simple way.

```
public class FtpUtility{
private FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

public boolean retriveFileFromApp(String srcFile, String destFile){
    boolean flag = false;
    try{
        connectToFtp()
        File dest = new File(destFile);

        if(!dest.exists())
            dest.mkdirs();
        if(dest.exists())
            dest.delete();
        FileOutputStream destStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        ftpClient.retrieveFile(srcFile, destStream);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //exception handling
    }
    finally{
        disconnect();
    }
    return flag;
}



private boolean connectToFtp(){
    boolean flag = false;
    try{
        ftpClient.connect(appserverip); // connect to ftp
        flag = ftpClient.login(ftpUserId, ftpPassword); 
    }           
    catch(Exception e){
        //exception handling
    }

    return flag;
}

private void disconnect(){
    try{
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //some exception handling   
    }

}
}
```

Now while multiple users are using this application, they are simultaneously connecting using an instance of this class and then disconnecting. Even a single user is connecting and disconnecting for each file transfer.

1. How can I effectively do this like connecting once, then doing the all transfer and then disconnecting, not opening and closing the connection for each transfer.
2. Will use of static help? If yes how?

Comment: you are connecting to the ftp and disconnecting. between these two actions you can pass as many files as you want.

Comment: It's actually generating a barcode during every business process and that barcode is transfered to web server to be displayed on a webpage. No way more than one file can be transfered for one business process

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work. Either the FTP client is static and you connect it once and use it serially via synchronization, or it is per-session and each session creates and connects and uses its own concurrently. Your present mixture of both can't work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remove the static when I copy pasted the code. I was trying that thing. The question is now edited.